# Data structures for linking blockchain accounts

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, hash-tree, zero-knowledge

I want to use a data structure like merkle tree in a hypothetical blockchain that, if needed, can fast check whether a wallet/account has received directly or indirectly from a specific list of wallets/accounts in the past. And in an ideal case, how much of the current balance of this wallet has been received from the list.
Considering that this data structure needs to be optimized in size and computing , what solution do you suggest?